# RethinkDB: custom scoring (like Elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, rethinkdb

I recently discovered RethinkDB, and find it's query language to be much simpler than Elasticsearch. The only use case I haven't been able to find a solution for is specifying how to score results based on the document's fields, like you can do in Elasticsearch (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/script-score.html). Is there a way to score the query results in RethinkDB and return only the top-n results?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a query like `r.table('comments').filter(r.row('name').eq('tldr'))`, then you can do something like `r.table('comments').filter(r.row('name').eq('tldr')).map({score: CALCULATE_SCORE(r.row), row: r.row}).orderBy('score').limit(n)` to return the top `n` results.  Note that his does work proportional to the number of results in the original query.  If that's too expensive, you can do something similar with an index by writing `r.table('comments').indexCreate('score', CALCULATE_SCORE(r.row))` and then writing `r.table('comments').orderBy({index: 'score'}).limit(n)`.